# Books about Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 development

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am looking for a book that can help me to understand extension and development for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Online and On-Premise.

What books are best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are few links that can guide you:

- [Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Step by Step](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735648905)
- [Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672335387)

You have [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:6rkGk3Qa5QQJ:blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/02/01/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-book-club.aspx%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=ubuntu) a long list with books

Maybe you can take a look [here](http://www.wowebook.be/book/working-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/).

> Configure, adapt, and extend Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011—guided by two
>   of the leading implementation specialists in the field. Whether you’re
>   an IT professional, **a developer**, or a power user, you’ll get
>   pragmatic, hands-on insights for customizing CRM in your
>   organization—with or without programming.